# "They encamped at Rissah" Bamidbar 33:21

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, masei, tur

The [verse 21 of chapter 33](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.33.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Sefer Bamidbar tells us the Bnei Israel encamped at Rissah.
On this verse, the [Baal Haturim](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.33.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Numbers.33.21.1&lang2=bi) comments: **ויחנו ברסה:** *שנתרוססו שם*

How does it mean and what is he referring to?

Comment: relevant: https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11a.19?lang=bi&with=SEFARIA%20COMMUNITY%20TRANSLATION&lang2=en or perhaps connected somehow to להרוס to destroy?

Comment: @Loewian, assuming that all the stations are listed in order in parshat Masei, Rissah is four stations after Ritmah - with the episode of the meraglim in parshat Sh'lach - and right after Rissah they encamped in Kehelat - where Korach and his group rebelled. If the meaning שנתרוססו is either collapse or destroy, what episode in the desert is it referring to? The magefah after the incident of Korach where 14,700 people died? Opened to suggestion here.

Comment: The word נתרוססו is in the form Hitpael, in which the third fourth and fifth letters (skipping prefixes and presumably the “ו” in the middle, which is sometimes found in hitpael) are the root letters. So in this case, it seems to be that the root is רוסס which, in modern Hebrew, means to spray. I don’t know if this is the meaning in ancient Hebrew, but it’s a possible lead @Loewian

Comment: @Loani, could this spraying/splashing be a reference of mei parah adumah and parshat Chukat?

Comment: @Eli83 it could... i (or someone else) would have to look at mepharshim for any more information about this. (Although of the places that I know why they’re called what they’re called, I think most of them have to do specifically with sins that bnei Yisra’el committed).

Comment: Although now that I look at the pesukim @Eli83, Rissah is mentioned *before* the place where Ba’al haturim says Korach argued with moshe- which was before parah adumah. So at least according to Ba’al haturim, (unless the rule אין מוקדם ומאוחר בתורה applies here) this is probably before parah adumah.